# C++ / R: RInside in Windows 7 machine

Tags: c++, r, windows, compilation, rcpp

This question is related to: [C++ and R: Create a .so or .dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975927/c-and-r-create-a-so-or-dll?noredirect=1#comment59610495_35975927) plus i have read the questions and replies of these posts:

1. [Compiling RInside programs on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928863/compiling-rinside-programs-on-windows)
2. [Problem with compiling RInside examples under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650063/problem-with-compiling-rinside-examples-under-windows)

I try to run the code provided as an example in the answer provided

```
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 

  std::string txt =                   // load library, run regression, create summary
    "suppressMessages(require(stats));"     
    "swisssum <- summary(lm(Fertility ~ . , data = swiss));" 
    "print(swisssum)";             
  R.parseEvalQ(txt);                  // eval command, no return

  // evaluate R expressions, and assign directly into Rcpp types
  Rcpp::NumericMatrix     M( (SEXP) R.parseEval("swcoef <- coef(swisssum)"));                 
  Rcpp::StringVector cnames( (SEXP) R.parseEval("colnames(swcoef)"));
  Rcpp::StringVector rnames( (SEXP) R.parseEval("rownames(swcoef)")); 

  std::cout << "\n\nAnd now from C++\n\n\t\t\t";
  for (int i=0; i<cnames.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << std::setw(11) << cnames[i] << "\t";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i<rnames.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << std::setw(16) << rnames[i] << "\t";
    for (int j=0; j<cnames.size(); j++) {
      std::cout << std::setw(11) << M(i,j) << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  exit(0);
}
```

The error in the CMD is the following

```
C:\Users\DON\Desktop>R CMD SHLIB final.cpp
g++ -m64 -I"C:/R/R-3.2.4/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/
local323/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c final.cpp -o final.o
final.cpp:1:74: fatal error: RInside.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [final.o] Error 1
Warning message:
comando ejecutado 'make -f "C:/R/R-3.2.4/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/R/R-3.2.4/shar
e/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)
' SHLIB="final.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="final.o"' tiene estatus 2
```

Clearly it cant find the `RInside.h` header. I have the R installed in a folder without spaces. The PATH in global variables have: `C:\R\R-3.2.4\bin; C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin`

I understand that in the CMD i cant introduce comands like

```
$ export PKG_LIBS=‘Rscript -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()"‘ # if Rcpp older than 0.11.0
$ export PKG_CXXFLAGS=‘Rscript -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()"‘
```

Which first defines and exports two relevant environment variables which R CMD SHLIB then relies on (as put in the [FAQ file](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf))

*Any advice on this? I need to do a `Makefile` for each `cpp` file that i want to compile?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in  your approach.  You did

```
R CMD SHLIB final.cpp
```

which is *nowhere* given as the correct approach for working with [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html).

*Because we need to tell R about headers and libraries for several components*, you are supposed to

```
cd inst/examples/standard
make                    # build all
```

or

```
make rinside_sample3    # build just this
```

or, if you're on that OS,

```
make -f Makefile.win    # all
```

or

```
make -f Makefile.win rinside_sample3
```

as the `Makefile` tells R where do find this.  That also answers your second question:  One `Makefile` per directory will do.  And *look* at the `Makefile`: it sets *several* include directives; your approach only dealt with Rcpp so *of course* you get an error about `RInside.h` not found.

I think you keep asking the same question over and over.

Comment: the output is an exe and not a dll. So when you have R code inside C++ no dll or .so can be made?

Comment: Please re-read what RInside is for, and what Rcpp and other extensions are.  Getting an `.exe` from RInside is very much a feature.

Comment: Maybe i need to buy your book then :) Thanks