# Error when compiling RInside examples on Windows

Tags: r, rcpp, rinside

I have an issue compiling the RInside examples on Windows.

In Rstudio, running

```
sourceCpp("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/RInside/examples/standard/rinside_sample0.cpp")
```

gives

```
fatal error: RInside.h: No such file or directory
```

From the command promt, running

```
cd C:\Users\Admin\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\RInside\examples\standard
make -f Makefile.win rinside_sample0
```

gives

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : aucun package nommé 'Rcpp' n'est trouvé
Error in loadNamespace(name) : aucun package nommé 'RInside' n'est trouvé
```

Apparently these packages are not found, so I tried the following:

1. Ran this from the command line `set R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.2`
2. Checked that Rtools and R dirs are present in the path
3. Modified the Makefile.win like so:

`R_LIBS_USER :=     "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/3.5"`

`R_ARCH :=      --arch x64`

But still getting the same errors. Any help? Thanks

---

EDIT: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5650694/5224236) might provide a solution by including this line of code somewhere

```
export R_LIBS_SITE=c:/R/site-library
```

However I don't know where to include it.

---

EDIT2 I have tried to reinstall `Rcpp` and `RInside` in both library locations (by running RStudio as admin)

```
remove.packages("Rcpp", lib = .libPaths())
remove.packages("RInside", lib = .libPaths())
install.packages("RInside", lib = .libPaths())
install.packages("Rcpp", lib = .libPaths())
library("RInside")
library("Rcpp")
```

In RStudio I still have the same error using `sourceCpp`, however, using the comand prompt and `make` approach I do get a different error:

```
make -f Makefile.win rinside_sample0 
g++.exe: error: Files/R/R-3.5.2/library/RInside/include: No such file or directory
```

I suppose the space in the path is the problem " Files..." will try to reinstall R in a non-spaced path

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034628/c-r-rinside-in-windows-7-machine/ and number of other duplicates.  In a nutshell, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi Dirk, I followed exactly the steps you described in this answer you just provided. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You and your R installation are fighting. It tells you it has no Rcpp or RInside.  Which makes compiling RInside examples a little difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling R in a path without spaces, installing the latest packages, and setting `R_HOME` environment variable to the new installation folder `C:\R\R-3.5.2` solved the problem.

```
remove.packages("Rcpp", lib = .libPaths())
remove.packages("RInside", lib = .libPaths())
install.packages("RInside", lib = .libPaths())
install.packages("Rcpp", lib = .libPaths())
library("RInside")
library("Rcpp")
```